# Reorder PHP array based on a common value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The only thing i care about here is sizes. I need to break into a new level of array and add it in, grouping them together.

I essentially need them all in grouped in their own array so i can loop through them and do something else.

Current Array:

```
[0] => Array 
    (
         [name] => random name 2
         [sizes] => ["XS","S","M","L","XL","XXL"]
    )
[1] => Array
    (
         [name] => random name 1
         [sizes] => One Size
    )
[2] => Array
    (
         [name] => random name 3
         [sizes] => ["XS","S","M","L","XL","XXL"]
    )
```

Wanted:

```
[0] => Array 
    (
         [0] => Array
            (
                 [name] => random name 1
                 [sizes] => One Size
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
         [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => random name 2
                [sizes] => ["XS","S","M","L","XL","XXL"]
            )
         [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => random name 3
                [sizes] => ["XS","S","M","L","XL","XXL"]
            )
    )
```

Comment: Why is 3 before 2? And what have you tried?

Comment: And what will happen if product 4 has size range S -> L?

Comment: The 3 is random, just ignore that, ill change now. If it has size range S -> L then ill want it to group exactly like the two above, in [2] => Array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the array and create a new array with the size as the key for now.
Later with array_values we remove the associative keys.

```
foreach($arr as $item){
    $new[$item['sizes']][] = $item;
}
$new = array_values($new); // remove associative
```

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Not sure I understand what you mean. The key in the example above will be the string "sizes". Yes it does look like an array but print_r would not have printed it that way if it was an array.

Comment: Yes.. If it was not print_r would have written it as [sizes] => array( ...... but it doesn't. Not that none of the other strings are enclosed with `"` but they are still strings.